# Язык C, typedef, эквивалентность типа и синонима

Tags: c, typedef

Подскажите, полностью ли эквивалентны тип и его синоним?

Если функция просит объект или указатель на объект определенного типа, можно ли ей давать синоним, ну и наоборот?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Краткий ответ, не тянущий на ответ - да.

`typedef` *не* создает нового типа, он дает новое имя старому типу.

Comment: Отличный ответ, больше бы таких)

Comment: @Максим Краткость - с.т. :)